# How does the Lorentz factor (gamma) affect Lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, velocity, inertial-frames

Does the lorentz factor in lorentz transformations of space and time between reference frames mean that time and space increase the amount that they shift at an exponential rate as v approaches c? Does this shift grow at an exponentially higher or lower rate as v approaches c? does the lorentz factor being in both the space and time transformations somehow cancel so that the increase in the shifting of spacetime stays constant as v approaches c? What is the effect of the lorentz factor on the shifting of spacetime as v approaches c?
Image credit to: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/veltran.html
[image: Description of lorentz transformations.]

Comment: (a) I think you mean an ever increasing rate, not an exponential rate. (b) Why not calculate $\gamma$ for some different values of $v$ and see what effect it has in the Lorentz transforms?

Comment: Are you the person who made the graphic? If not, then please credit the author.

Comment: Time and space **shift** now?

Comment: What do you mean by the shift staying constant?

Comment: Philip Wood, a) The wording there does not really matter, they essentially mean the same thing, and b) I know that the lorentz factor increases from 1 at an exponential rate as v approaches c, but I am having trouble figuring out how this effects the coordinate transform equations. Ben Crowell, Added image credit. WillO, what I mean by time and space shifting is the change in the coordinates of an event between two reference frames that either experience different gravity or are in relative motion. Benjanim, What I mean by this is t' and x' increasing at a constant rate as v increases.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at the math: Clearly when $\vec{v} = 0$, then $\gamma =1$ and so we expect neither a shift in time or space. That's pretty self-explanatory, after all, it's just a stationary frame isn't it?

What about when we start increasing $\vec{v}$? Well,

$\frac{d\gamma}{d\vec{v}} = \frac{d}{d\vec{v}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}} = - \frac{\vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = \frac{v^2c^2}{c^2-v^2}. $

The point here being that as $v$ approaches $c$,  then the change in $\gamma$ becomes assymtotic. Plugging in a $v$ close to $c$ produces a near 0 denominator, and thus $\gamma \rightarrow \infty.$ Thus it's fair to claim that $\gamma$ increases at an increasing rate, and thus time dilation and length contraction will as well. Finally, let us look at velocity.

if $t' = \gamma(t-\frac{xv}{c^2})$, then $t = \frac{t'}{\gamma} + \frac{xv}{c^2}$.

Plugging this in, $x'=\gamma(x-vt)=\gamma(x-\frac{t'v}{\gamma}-\frac{xv^2}{c^2})$.
After some further simplification, you will arrive at the conclusion that $\gamma$ is not necessary for this velocity equation. That having been said, there is still a $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$ term in the velocity equation. As such there are still relativistic effects even without the Lorentz coefficient.

Comment: Nice job with the math! However, what I was asking is what is the effect of the lorentz factor on the rate of change of the lorentz coordinate equations. How does the difference between x and x'/t and t' change as v approaches C? How is this affected by gamma? Also, I played around with your final equation, and I don't quite see how you can fully factor out the lorentz factor (gamma). However, I do appreciate you solving for the derivative of gamma and such. How does this affect the derivative (rate of change) of the full lorentz coordinate transformations over v and what is said derivative?